# ¿Cómo arreglar error "Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-29" en Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

Tengo el siguiente error al intentar compilar:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileDebugAidl'.
> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-29
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 19s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed
> with exit code 1

Mis dependencias:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+11
  path_provider: ^1.6.18
  path: ^1.7.0
```

Antes estaba todo bien, el emulador funciona correctamente pero no compila el programa, fue de repente...

Estos son mis SDK:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intenta ejecutar esto : flutter pub cache repair

Comment: No funcionó... también probé flutter clean.

Comment: Cual es el log? estas en android studio?.

Comment: Es Visual Studio Code, el log es el que cito, solo ese.

Comment: También probé correrlo en AS y me da el mismo error.

Comment: instala el sdk de la plataforma para la que estas compilando, la 29, y revisa que todos tus componentes sean compatibles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tenía instalado era el build-tools para SDK 29. Se arregló el problema al descargar el Platform 29 desde el SDK Manager de Android Studio.